# How to use custom search box for google custom search?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-custom-search

How to use custom search box for google custom search?

I need to change the style for google search box into my own style..

Comment: have you got the google custom search implemented ? or you just want to know how to override the styles ?

Comment: you need google custom search or want to custom google search or both?

Comment: Actually I have a search box designed , I need to use that, instead of using google's search box..

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this:

```html
  <div id="globalsearch" class="globalsearch">
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search" target="_blank" class="navbar_search"> <input type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="yoursite.com"  id="pn"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="s" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="securitytoken" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="do" value="process" />
    <span class="textboxcontainer"><span><input placeholder="Search..." type="text" value="" name="query" class="textbox" tabindex="99"/></span></span>
   </form>
  </div>
```

you can custom your class and css

- change this: `value="yoursite.com"`